# NAS share access on Windows 10 getting error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated "

Tags: windows-10, nas

I am trying to access a share on a WD Ex2 Ultra from a Windows 10 machine.
On our site we authenticate through Azure using PINs.

On my machine when I try to access a share on the NAS which has been secured with a password I get the error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated" when I try to access the share through file explorer.

Have tested on another machine on our network and am able to type in a user name and password and access it fine. Both machines are windows 10.

I checked the setting  "Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication" and it is disabled.

UPATE - I was successfully able to access the share if I login into winbdows using using my password instead of my PIN, however on the other machine I tested the user is able to login using a PIN and still access the share using the password setup on the NAS. I want to be able to login using my PIN if possible and still access the share.

Answer (score 2):

I preceded my username with the servername and a backslash, like NAS1\denis , and got past that error. I had tried everything else and exhausted the Synology tech support guy's repertoire. In the Windows Map Network Drive authentication dialog, try that trick and see if it helps.